# Oracle - use regular expression to format capturing groups

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm looking to use REGEXP_REPLACE (or equivalent functions) to format my strings to be fixed length outputs.

For example. My input is always 3 sets of random strings, delimited by commas.
I want the output to have a fixed length of 10 characters (filled by '_') for each capturing group.

input:

```
abc,def,ghi
085,10,1234567
long words,tom,jerry
```

Desired output:

```
_______abc_______def_______ghi
_______085________10___1234567
long words_______tom_____jerry
```

So the code would be something like:

```
select regexp_replace( input, '([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)',
                       LPAD('\1', '_', 10) || LPAD('\2', '_', 10) || LPAD('\3', '_', 10) ) 
from <table>
```

That apparently didn't work out as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Backreferences are only parsed as such in string patterns. You can't use them as arguments to other functions, they are treated as literal strings then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With multiple replacements and concatenation you can do this:

```
select
    lpad(regexp_replace('085,10,1234567', ',.*$', ''), 10, '_') || -- remove the first period and everything after it
    lpad(regexp_replace('085,10,1234567', '^[^,]+,|,[^,]+$', ''), 10, '_') || -- remove the first period, everything before it, and the last period plus everything after it
    lpad(regexp_replace('085,10,1234567', '^.*,', ''), 10, '_') as whatever -- remove the last period and everything before it
from
    dual
```

Just replace `'085,10,1234567'` with your `input`.

This example produces:

```
_______085________10___1234567
```

Comment: That's great.I didn't think to call it 3 times!

Comment: @Samuel I'm glad you like it, feel free to mark my answer as accepted :)